# Curtate Expectation of life aged x question

Tags: actuarial-science

[Curtate Expectation of life aged x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y8Jf.png)

So I did
@k=0, P(60)= 0.9

@k=1, P(61)= 0.9*[0.9*(1-(0.1*1)) = 0.729

@k=2, P(62)= 0.9*0.729* [0.9*(1-(0.1*2)) = 0.47239

Not sure if that's right, or where to go from there. Can anyone help with a detailed working for this question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whaz is the meaning of $e_x$ and $ P_{x+k}$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $e_x$ denotes the complete expectation of life at age $x$. And $p_x $ denotes the probability that the person of age $x$ will survive til the next year.

$$\begin{array} {r c l  }  e_{60} 
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k\geqslant1} \phantom0_k p_{60} \\
&=& \displaystyle p_{60} + \phantom0_2 p_{60} + \phantom0_3 p_{60} 
+ \phantom0_3 p_{60} \cdot e_{63}  \\
&=& 0.9 + 0.9 \cdot 0.81 + 0.9  \cdot 0.81  \cdot 0.72 (1 + 13.5) \\
&=& \boxed{9.23976 }
\end{array}$$